# A Moq'ed services methods are not called when service is passed to generic method on base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

I have a generic method on a base class for managing list items:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModelHandler<T> : BaseLogger, IViewModelHandler<T>
    where T : IViewModel
{
    public abstract void Handle(T viewModel);

    protected ISet<TE> ManageListItems<TE>(int[] selectedItemIds, ISet<TE> list, IService<TE> service)
        where TE : IEntity
    {
        try
        {

... param checking and code to remove unwanted items not included for brevity

            if (selectedItemIds.Any())
            {
                var itemIdsToAdd = selectedItemIds.Where(id => list.All(x => x.Id != id)).ToList();
                if (itemIdsToAdd.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var id in itemIdsToAdd)
                    {
                        var item = service.GetById(id);
                        list.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            return list;
        }

...catch block removed for brevity

    }
}
```

I have a class that inherits this base class.

```
public class ConcreteViewModelHandler : BaseViewModelHandler<ConcreteViewModel>
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IMyListItemsService _myListItemsService

    public ConcreteViewModelHandler (IMyService myService, IMyListItemsService myListItemsService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _myListItemsService = myListItemsService
    }

    public override void Handle(ConcreteViewModel viewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var myEntity = viewModel.Id.HasValue
                               ? _myService.GetById(viewModel.Id.Value)
                               : new MyEntity();

            myEntity.ListToManage = ManageListItems(viewModel.SelectedItemIds, myEntity.ListToManage, _myListItemsService);

...create/update removed for brevity

        }

...catch block removed for brevity

    }
}
```

I am trying to test the Handle method. In my test I mock the service, and I setup the 'GetById' method to return a new instance of my class

```
_myListItemsServiceMock = new Mock<IMyListItemsService>();
_myListItemsServiceMock
      .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
      .Returns(new MyListItem{ Id : 1});
```

My test does not pass, when I step through the code the call to `service.GetById(id);`  in my base class returns null. This is the first project on which I have used Moq properly so I fear my inexperience with the framework has me missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As requested adding the TestFixture...

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConcreteViewModelHandlerTestFixture
{
    private Mock<IMyService> _myServiceMock;
    private Mock<IMyListItemsService> _myListItemsServiceMock;

    #region Test Data

    private readonly ConcreteViewModel _viewModel = new ConcreteViewModel
    {
        Id = 1,
    };

    #endregion

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _myServiceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();
        _myServiceMock
            .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(new MyEntity { Id: 1});

        _myListItemsServiceMock = new Mock<IMyListItemsService>();
        _myListItemsServiceMock
            .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(new MyListItem{ Id : 1});
    }


    [Test]
    public void _the_handle_method_works()
    {
        //arrange
        var handler = new ConcreteViewModelHandler(_myServiceMock.Object, _myListItemsServiceMock.Object);

        // act
        handler.Handle(_viewModel);

        // assert
        // no assertions yet as the code falls over
    }
}
```

Adding more detail as requested by @Quinton Bernhardt

interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    //Guid Guid { get; }
    int UpdateId { get; set; }
}
```

base class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }

    protected BaseEntity(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual int UpdateId { get; set; }
}
```

and the MyListItem class

```
public class MyLIstitem : BaseEntity
{
    public MyLIstitem ()
    {
    }

    public MyLIstitem (int id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }


    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post rest of your test code?

Comment: @GinjaNinja I can't see anything obviously wrong in the code. When you debug the `Handle` method, can you see the actual type of `_myService`? Can we see the definition of `IMyService`?

Comment: Exactly which lines fails and with which exception?

Comment: @memesv: the OP says the line `service.GetById(id); in my base class returns null` and the only placethat occurs is in the `ManageListItems` method in the base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description says:

> My test does not pass, when I step through the code the call to
>   service.GetById(id); in my base class returns null.

So it must be the call to `ManageListItems<TE>()` that fails on the line:

```
var item = service.GetById(id);
```

Hopefully i'm correct as it's an assumption [using the information provided].

Does `IMyListItemService` implement `IService<IEntity>` ? 'cos your code implies it.

The only weirdness i can see is that the last parameter of `ManageListItems<TE>()` expects a parameter of type `IService<TE> where TE is IEntity` which is used to make the call to `service.GetById(id)`.

```
protected ISet<TE> ManageListItems<TE>(int[] selectedItemIds, ISet<TE> list, IService<TE> service)
```

*stay with me..., it makes sense later on...*

But the object you supply to that method from your concrete class is of type `IMyListItemsService` as can be seen from the following in the `Handle` method:

```
myEntity.ListToManage = ManageListItems(viewModel.SelectedItemIds, myEntity.ListToManage, _myListItemsService);
```

*what i think is happening...* your setup of `GetById` should be on the `IService` instead of the `IMyListItemsService`

When setting up the GetById on the on the list service, instead of this:

```
    _myListItemsServiceMock
        .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new IMyListItem{ Id : 1});
```

try

```
    _myListItemsServiceMock.As<IService>()
        .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new IMyListItem{ Id : 1});
```

or

```
    _myListItemsServiceMock.As<IService<IEntity>>()
        .Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new IMyListItem{ Id : 1});
```

Comment: Firstly apologies for the tardy reply, but your assumptions are correct and your suggestions make sense, but the call to `service.GetById(id);` still returns null. I changed the implementation of the `_myListItemsServiceMock` to convert it to the base type, I also created a new mock as follows `var _myListItemsServiceMock2 = new Mock<IService<IEntity>>(); _myListItemsServiceMock2.As<IMyListItemsService>().Setup(s => s.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new IMyListItem{ Id : 1});` and this also returned null...

Comment: I edited my original question with the details for MyListItem (the 'I' prefix was a typo)

Comment: I went through the code and i found that the GetById() method was defined in the base in interface and also in another interface that inherited from the base interface, this double definition was causing the problem. @Quinton I marked your answer as the solution as the ` _myListItemsServiceMock.As<IService<IEntity>>()` suggestion was actually the solution once I had fixed my bugs!